# cannot switch between child state in angular ui.router

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Following is my code and its [codepen](http://codepen.io/rizvanhaider/pen/WGjBbj) . I am unable to switch from nav4's child1 to child2, or child3, the url changes but the view doesn't, but after clicking on any child and then refreshing the browser loads the content of state.

**HTML**

```
<nav class="advance-navbar">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav adv-nav">
                        <li class="dropdown active">
                            <a ui-sref="nav1" class="dropdown-toggle"> <span>nav1</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a ui-sref="nav2" class="dropdown-toggle"><span>nav2</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a ui-sref="nav3" class="dropdown-toggle"><span>nav3</span></a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a ui-sref="nav4" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">nav4 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a ui-sref="nav4.child41">child1</a></li>
                                <li><a ui-sref="nav4.child42">child2</a></li>
                                <li><a ui-sref="nav4.child43">child3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

**JS**

```
var example = angular.module("example", ['ui.router']);
example.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
            .state('nav1', {
                url: '/nav1',
                template: '<h1>{{stateurl}}</h1',
                controller: 'dummyCtrl',
                data : {elastic_index : 'nav1'}
            })
            .state('nav2', {
                url: '/nav2',
                template: '<h1>{{stateurl}}</h1',
                controller: 'dummyCtrl',
                data : {elastic_index : 'nav2'}
            })
            .state('nav3', {
                url: '/nav3',
               template: '<h1>{{stateurl}}</h1',
                controller: 'dummyCtrl',
                data : {elastic_index : 'nav3'}
            })
            .state('nav4', {
                url: '/nav4',
                template: '<h1>{{stateurl}}</h1',
                controller: 'dummyCtrl',
                data : {elastic_index : 'nav4'}
            })
            .state('nav4.child41', {
                url: '/child41',
                template: '<h1>{{stateurl}}</h1',
                controller: 'dummyCtrl',
                data : {elastic_index : 'child41'}
            })
            .state('nav4.child42', {
                url: '/child42',
                template: '<h1>{{stateurl}}</h1',
                controller: 'dummyCtrl',
                data : {elastic_index : 'child42'}
            })
            .state('nav4.child43', {
                url: '/child43',
               template: '<h1>{{stateurl}}</h1',
                controller: 'dummyCtrl',
                data : {elastic_index : 'child43'}
            });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/nav1');
  });
  example.controller('dummyCtrl', function ($scope, $state){
      console.info($state)
      $scope.stateurl= $state.current.data.elastic_index;
  })
```

[CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/rizvanhaider/pen/WGjBbj)

**Edit**
In actual app I have same *templateURL* file for both parent and child state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you do not need to show the nav4 itself, so make it abstract.
An abstract state is implicitly activated when one of its child states are activated. This is useful when we need to prepend a url to all the child state urls we need to insert a template with its own ui-view that the child states will fill.
So it will be like this

```
var example = angular.module("example", ['ui.router']);
example.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
    .state('nav1', {
        url: '/nav1',
        templateUrl: 'templates/dummy.html',
        controller: 'dummyCtrl',
        data: {
            elastic_index: 'nav1'
        }
    })
    .state('nav2', {
        url: '/nav2',
        templateUrl: 'templates/dummy.html',
        controller: 'dummyCtrl',
        data: {
            elastic_index: 'nav2'
        }
    })
    .state('nav3', {
        url: '/nav3',
        templateUrl: 'templates/dummy.html',
        controller: 'dummyCtrl',
        data: {
            elastic_index: 'nav3'
        }
    })
    .state('nav4', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/nav4',
        template: '<ui-view/>',
        controller: 'dummyCtrl',
        data: {
            elastic_index: 'nav4'
        }
    })
    .state('nav4.child41', {
        url: '/child41',
        templateUrl: 'templates/dummy.html',
        controller: 'dummyCtrl',
        data: {
            elastic_index: 'child41'
        }
    })
    .state('nav4.child42', {
        url: '/child42',
        templateUrl: 'templates/dummy.html',
        controller: 'dummyCtrl',
        data: {
            elastic_index: 'child42'
        }
    })
    .state('nav4.child43', {
        url: '/child43',
        templateUrl: 'templates/dummy.html',
        controller: 'dummyCtrl',
        data: {
            elastic_index: 'child43'
        }
    });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/nav1');
});

example.controller('dummyCtrl', function ($scope, $state) {
console.info($state)
$scope.stateurl = $state.current.data.elastic_index;
})
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to add `<div ui-view></div>` to the parent template, so the router will place the child view there

look here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ALrvPw

Comment: Thanks @WAlks for your reply,  it works fine. but in my actual app my all states (both parent and child) have same html, how do I implement it in that scenario.